# What means "to get bitten in the rump"

Tags: meaning, phrase-meaning

Today I've found this phrase:

> With great power comes the great chance to get bitten in the rump.

It sounds interesting but I couldn't understand the part *to get bitten in the rump*.

What does it mean ? Is there a typo ?

Comment: I don't know for sure what the text you've cited is about, but "rump" is 'the round area of flesh at the top of the back legs of an animal that has four legs', so the meaning seems to be literal.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is a variation on the phrase *bitten in the ass*.

[TFD](http://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/bite+in+the+ass) (which is an excellent source for defining idioms) says:

> **bite (someone) in the ass**
>   To punish or take revenge on someone for his or her misjudgment or misdeed(s). Typically the punishment or revenge is not exacted by a person, but as a general consequence for the misbehavior itself. Not used in polite conversation.
>
> *Your poor treatment of your employees might come back to bite you in the ass some day.
>
>   I got too greedy with my gambling, and now it has bitten me in the ass.*

The word *rump* has been substituted for *ass* in the sentence you have quoted to make it less vulgar and more polite.